# Eigenvectors’ entries distribution of a random matrix taken from a GOE distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, random-matrices

Heads up: I’m a physicist.

I’ve read in this physics [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.05339.pdf) that the eigenvectors of a random matrix $V$, taken from the Gaussian Orthogonal Ensemble (GOE) that:

> In relation to the eigenvectors, the main assertion is that the orthogonal matrix of eigenvectors $(\psi^1, · · · , \psi^N )$ is distributed according to the Haar measure on the orthog- onal group $O(N)$.

(I know nothing about Haar measures and what I read was really complicated for my maths level) Then the author continues to say

> For our purposes, this means that the eigenvectors have independent and random gaussian entries, up to normalization. Matemathically:
> $$[\psi_i^a]=0 \quad[\psi^a_i\psi^b_j]= \frac{1}{N}\delta_{ij}\delta^{ab},$$ where $[p]$ denotes the average of the random variable $p$ over the matrix ensemble.

where $\psi^a_i$ is the $i$-th entry of eigenvector $\psi^a$.

**Could somebody explain me how the author obtained those statistical moments above and what should one do to obtain higher moments (like $[\psi^a_i\psi^b_j\psi^c_k\psi^d_l]$)?**

---

As it stands, to me it just looks as if $\psi^a_i$ was just some independent random variable and we were taking its expectation value with respect to a 1d Gaussian distribution (mean? deviation?...). Hence $[\psi_i^a]=0$ as it is like doing $[x]$ with a 1d Gaussian distribution. Similarly for $[\psi^a_i\psi^b_j]= \frac{1}{N}\delta_{ij}\delta^{ab}$ because unless $\psi^a_i=\psi^b_j$ we have the product of two “$[x]$” which we already know is zero.

**But what about the $\frac{1}{N}$? I really need to understand why that $N$ is there as later on in the paper one sees higher moments with different powers of $N$ dividing through.**

Comment: The intuition behind the $1/n$ factor is as follows: if you take $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2 I_n)$, it will have expected squared norm 1 when you take $\sigma^2=1/n$.

Comment: @md5 I don’t quite understand,  could you perhaps explain a bit your notation? Also, how does that generalise for say $[x_1x_2x_3x_4]$?